# WP 2 Domains One Hosting Account

Tags: wordpress, multiple-domains

Alright, howdy
  I have a client who I built a site for, call it www.site1.com

That client is now expanding and creating a new product line so they bought another domain, call it www.site2.net, and have tasked me with making that site as well. They have one deluxe hosting account with godaddy. Now I was wondering what the best way to do this would be. Site1 is a wp setup and they want to use the same wp setup and theme for site2. I started out setting up a subfolder /site1/site2 and had the domain point to the subfolder on the hosting. Entering in site2.net will take me to the correct subfolder. Just for fun I put in a whole other wp installation in the subfolder and installed the theme, started tinkering. Everything looked fine until I went back to site1 and saw that the pages were not loading. So I moved web.config up to the root folder and site1 works now but site2 pages won't load. I don't know enough about this but I've gathered that site2 will inherit the web.config properties setup from the root folder. Any suggestions on how to fix this or make this work? I know my client doesn't ideally want to pay for another hosting account so I'd like to make this work on the one hosting. I'm not very far at all on site2 but site1 is all set. Thanks in advance for any tips on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WordPress within a WordPress, the child Wordpress folder needs to have the .htaccess information include that directory structure

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site1/site2
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site1/site2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```